# Creating react app in nx workspace fails - yarn not found

Tags: reactjs, nrwl, nrwl-nx

I am following the NX tutorial [(here)](https://nx.dev/react/getting-started/getting-started) about creating react app but I get an error:

```
✔︎ tracking-platform (master) ✗ npm run nx -- generate 
@nrwl/react:application todos

> tracking-platform@0.0.0 nx /home/kklimczak/workspace/tracking-platform
> nx "generate" "@nrwl/react:application" "todos"

? In which directory should the application be generated? 
? Which stylesheet format would you like to use? CSS
? Would you like to configure routing for this application? No
/bin/sh: 1: yarn: not found
Package install failed, see above.
```

I use Ubuntu 19.04 with node v10.15.3 and npm 6.10.1. Do you know what wrong with this configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to install yarn

You can include an installation of yarn in your build script by adding

```
npm install yarn
```